# Problema al intentar incluir imagen como símbolo en capas de Geoserver

Tags: xml

Estoy intentando utilizar una imagen como símbolo en mi mapa en GeoServer. Quiero que los puntos rojos en mi mapa sean reemplazados por un símbolo específico, pero al intentar hacerlo, los puntos aparecen negros (tal como se aprecia en el mapa) en lugar de usar la imagen que especifiqué.

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

Utilicé el editor de capas de GeoServer para generar un código SLD (Styled Layer Descriptor) que define el estilo de los puntos en mi mapa. Aquí está el código SLD que generé:

[image]

Chequeé si era problema de la propia ubicación del archivo pero al buscarla por medio de la web, me resulta correcta la búsqueda: *http://localhost:8080/geoserver/styles/monomono.jpg*

[image]
¿Cómo solucionarlo?

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>monumentos</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Estilo de Monumento</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="styles/monomono.jpg"/>
                <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>25</Size> 
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. La etiqueta que se modificó en tu pregunta es lo que más tendría relación a la misma; sin embargo, muy probablemente obtengas ayuda en [gis.se] (en inglés), ya que [es.so] es un sitio de preguntas sobre _programación_.